# Date sorting issue if a extra budge digit using eg. "02/13/2017 0"

Tags: html, html-table, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter plugin for sorting my table.
I have a date column and with the date I have budge digit for example

"`02/13/2017` `0`"

I want to sort this only according to date.
But it's not working. I need quick suggestion for this question.
Here is some html for that:

```
<td role="gridcell">
  <div class="slds-truncate">
    <span class="uiOutputDate">02/13/2017</span>
    <span class="badge2">0</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Use the `extractMMDDYYYY` parser available in the [`parser-date-extract.js` file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date-extract.js) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1170/))

   ```
   <th class="sorter-extractMMDDYYYY">Date</th>
   ```
2. Use the `textExtraction` callback to target the element containing the date ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1169/))

   ```
   $(function() {
     $('table').tablesorter({debug: true,
       theme: 'blue',
       textExtraction: {
         0: function(node) {
           return $(node).find('.uiOutputDate').text() || $(node).text();
         }
       },
       widgets: ['zebra'],
     });
   });
   ```

   * Note that the `textExtraction` function in the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5b) only supports a single function ([ref](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#textExtraction)).